# how can I access an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a file `data.js` where there is an array with some navigation items.

```
export const footerNavigation = [
  {
    category: 'Resources',
    items: [
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Guides'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Blog'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Customer stories'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Glossery'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Resources',
    items: [
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Guides'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Blog'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Customer stories'
      },
      {
        href: '',
        text: 'Glossery'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

`Footer.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

import { footerNavigation } from '../data/data';

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {footerNavigation.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h3 className='text-lg font-bold mb-8'>{item.category}</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href=""></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer;
```

The task is to make sure there is an href value inside a link tag like `<a href={.href}</a>` and the value of the item here `<a>{.value}</a>`

I have a basic understanding how to map items that are in the initial array, but have no clue how to map the array that is inside an object which is inside the initial array.

Comment: the first one would be `item.items[0].href` for example - I imagine you'd want an `item.items.map` to create multiple `<li>`s though - why else do you have a `<ul>` - certainly not for nice formatting

Comment: also: [mapping within another map and printing multiple properties on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72680263/mapping-within-another-map-and-printing-multiple-properties-on-object/72680351#72680351)

Answer (score 2):

You only missing another items iteration:

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* category unique acts as key */}
      {footerNavigation.map(({ category, items }) => {
        return (
          <div key={category}>
            <h3 className="text-lg font-bold mb-8">{category}</h3>
            <ul>
              {/* text unique should be a key */}
              {items.map(({ href, text }) => (
                <a key={text} href={href}>
                  {text}
                </a>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: flag as duplicate, or at least add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! I'm quite new to this and trying to figure out what's what, so sorry for a dumb question.

Comment: Dont be sorry for learning